# Find function will not compile when searching through vectors

Tags: c++, vector

The following code should unregister a nickname stored in a vector, however the code errors on the find function and I don't understand why.

The error says 'assigning int from incompatible type' but I don't know how I can get the position of the vector element found via a different route.

```
if (userinput == "/unregister" && isAdmin == true) {
  cout << "Please enter the nickname to be unregistered.\n";
  cin >> newnick;
  if (isRegisteredUName(newnick) == true) {
    unamepos = find(unamevec.begin(), unamevec.end(), newnick)
    cout << "DEBUG: " << unamepos << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: You forgot to show us the types of any of your variables, but I guess `unamepos` is an integer, while `find` returns an iterator. Either change the type of `unamepos` or, if you want an index, do `unamepos = find(...) - unamevec.begin();`

Comment: We need more context but my bet is the same as the one of @MikeSeymour

Comment: You forgot the trailing semi-colon on that line.

Comment: Also you forgot to add semicolon (';') after call of `find()`, so your code can't be compiled.

Comment: Hey, forgive my briefness, I used a mobile device for this in limited time. There is actually that trailing semicolon but I guess I accidentally backspaced. The vector is a string, and I'd put the position variable unamepos as an integer. I will try the solutions suggested as soon as I return to my workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
unamepos = find(unamevec.begin(), unamevec.end(), newnick)
```

to

```
unamepos = find(unamevec.begin(), unamevec.end(), newnick);
```

This should work. Furthermore I have added a sample code which compiles and works in my environment

If the vector is integer type -

```
vector<int> checker;
std::vector<int>::iterator it;

it = find(checker.begin(), checker.end(),100);
```

If the vector is string type

```
vector<string> checker;

if(find(checker.begin(), checker.end(),"ab") != checker.end())
{
  //Do your task here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The two lines are the same.

Comment: Oh there is missing ; now I see :)

Comment: Yeah, in my actual code (not the copied version on my mobile) I have that semicolon, but it doesn't appear to compile, with the same error: error: `no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >')`

Comment: Also, my vector is declared as `vector <string> unamevec(2,"Administrator"); //Declare username vector.` and my unamepos is a string variable.

Comment: I'm still unsure about if that will give the correct result - it seems like it checks the vector for the entry to see if it is present, and if so, does whatever, but I'm looking for the position of that entry in the vector?

Comment: I your case you will need the position of that particular index right? In that case you need to do this - int pos = find(checker.begin(), checker.end(),"ab"); 

Now you need to check pos against checker.size() to see if it is out of bounds or not.

Comment: Well, I already have an if statement that looks for the element in the vector, so then I can hopefully use your suggestion anyway. However I'd need the search to use a variable that depends on user input as otherwise it'd delete a fixed username only.

Comment: I don't think so. I can't use something like "ab" though, only the variable newnick.

Comment: What happens if you use a variable instead of "ab"?

Comment: Same error as before but I just wished to make it clear that I can't use a fixed string for input. However I used Mike Seymour's solution as well for finding the index and it compiles!